# select every third number in for-loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a for-loop and then select every third number and write a line to the console.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=52; i++)
{
    if (something??)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Week" + i);
    }
}
```

I'm also trying to write it like this:

```
Week 1                Week 4            Week 7
Week 10               Week 13           Week 16
Week 19               Week 23           Week 25
```

etc up to 52...

A little help in the right direction would bee really nice!

EDIT:

Sorry I meant every third number...

Thanks so much for the help i was a little stuck for a while there, now i must figure out how to get the Weeks to show as above.. :)

Comment: You said _every fifth number_ but you increment your numbers with `3`? And `23` shouldn't be `22`? Because `19 + 3 = 22`..

Comment: Do you need every 5th or every 3rd week? That´s not clear.

Comment: Sorry i have cleard that up now.... sorry :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=52; i+=3)
{

}
```

You don't need to use an `if`  statement. You can just change the step of your loop, from 1 (`i++`), to the one you need, 3 (`i+=3`).

Answer (score 3):

THere seems to be some confusion at to whether you want th 3rd or 5th element. Either way, the method is the same, just replace 5 with 3

There are 2 options

```
 for (int i = 1; i <=52; i+=3)
```

OR

```
for (int i = 1; i <=52; i++)
          {
              if (i % 3 == 1)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Week" + i);
              }
          }
```

Comment: ah the remainder check, wat a champion

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to increment your variable in for loop by 5 or 3?

```
for (int i = 0; i <=52; i+=5)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Week" + i);
}
```

Comment: This oke knows what is up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integer as counter so you know when it has completed the if-statement 5 times. If it has been 5 times you can run the code and reset the counter.
Is this what you were looking for?

For the second part of your question I agree with Christos.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in learning LINQ you could do:

```
IEnumerable<string> thirdWeeks = Enumerable.Range(0, 52)
    .Where((week, index) => index % 3 == 0)
    .Select(week => string.Format("Week {0}", week + 1));
string allWeeksInOneLine = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, thirdWeeks);
Console.Write(allWeeksInOneLine);
```

If you want three-weeks-in-line groups like `Week 1                Week 4            Week 7`:

```
var weeksGrouped = thirdWeeks
    .Select((week, index) => new { week, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 3)
    .Select(g => String.Join("\t", g.Select(x => x.week)));
string allWeeksGrouped = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, weeksGrouped);
Console.Write(allWeeksGrouped);
```

Result:

```
Week 1  Week 4  Week 7
Week 10 Week 13 Week 16
Week 19 Week 22 Week 25
Week 28 Week 31 Week 34
Week 37 Week 40 Week 43
Week 46 Week 49 Week 52
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to that!

Comment: @user3727466: note that i've edited it to show you also how you can get the three-weeks-in-line requirement.